# C : how pthread dataspecific works?

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm not sure about how pthread dataspecific works : considering the next code (found on the web), does this means i can create for example 5 threads in the main, have a call to func in only some of them (let's say 2) those threads would have the data 'key' set to something (ptr = malloc(OBJECT_SIZE) ) and the other threads would have the same key existing but with a NULL value?

```
static pthread_key_t key;
static pthread_once_t key_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

static void
make_key()
{
  (void) pthread_key_create(&key, NULL);
}

func()
{
  void *ptr;

  (void) pthread_once(&key_once, make_key);
  if ((ptr = pthread_getspecific(key)) == NULL) {
    ptr = malloc(OBJECT_SIZE);
    ...
    (void) pthread_setspecific(key, ptr);
  }
  ...
}
```

Some explanation on how dataspecific works and how it may have been implemented in pthread (simple way) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. These calls are for thread-specific data. They're a way of giving each thread a "global" area where it can store what it needs, but only if it needs it.

The key is shared among all threads, since it's created with `pthread_once()` the first time it's needed, but the value given to that key is different for each thread (unless it remains set to NULL). By having the value a `void*` to a memory block, a thread that needs thread-specific data can allocate it and save the address for later use. And threads that don't call a routine that needs thread-specific data never waste memory since it's never allocated for them.

The one area where I have used them is to make a standard C library thread-safe. The `strtok()` function (as opposed to a thread-safe `strtok_r()` which was considered an abomination when we were doing this) in an implementation I was involved in used almost this exact same code the first time it was called, to allocate some memory which would be used by `strtok()` for storing information for subsequent calls. These subsequent calls would retrieve the thread-specific data to continue tokenizing the string without interfering with other threads doing the exact same thing.

It meant users of the library didn't have to worry about cross-talk between threads - they still had to ensure a single thread didn't call the function until the last one had finished but that's the same as with single-threaded code.

It allowed us to give a 'proper' C environment to each thread running in our system without the usual "you have to call these special non-standard re-entrant routines" limitations that other vendors imposed on their users.

As for implementation, from what I remember of DCE user-mode threads (which I think were the precursor to the current pthreads), each thread had a single structure which stored things like instruction pointers, stack pointers, register contents and so on. It was a very simple matter to add one pointer to this structure to achieve very powerful functionality with minimal cost. The pointer pointed to a array (linked list in some implementations) of key/pointer pairs so each thread could have multiple keys (e.g., one for `strtok()`, one for `rand()`).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is yes.  In simple terms, it allows each thread to allocate and save its own data.  This is roughly equivalent to w/o each thread simply allocating and passing around its own data structure.  The API saves you the trouble of passing the thread-local structure to all subfunctions, and allows you to look it up on demand instead.

The implementation really doesn't matter all that much (it may vary per-OS), as long as the results are the same.

You can think of it as a two-level hashmap.  The key specifies which thread-local "variable" you want to access, and the second level might perform a thread-id lookup to request the per-thread value.